# Weight painting issues

Tags: modeling, weight-painting

when i was weight painting a model i found that a part of my model (the left foot) was getting pulled by some other bone in the area i suspected is was the calf or the other foot, so i went back and re-did it several times yet it is still being pulled by something please help. Thank you! 
[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all the bones influencing geometry:

1. Select the mesh.
2. Get into Edit Mode.
3. Select the vertices you're interested in.
4. Hover your cursor over the 3d Viewport, hit `N`.
5. Scroll down until you see `Vertex Weights`.

[image]

From there, select the `Deform` option and you should be able to see all the influences.  If there's an influence that you don't want there, hit the X next to the VG name.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem, but I managed to fix it in the weight painting mode, don't forget to check all faces with 'z mode' activated (it's brighter).
You can also try to parent your bones in empty weight mode and paint all weight by hand.